# how to show emp leave balance in textbox1 based on leavetype selection

Tags: c#

I want to show emp leave balance in `textbox1` based on leavetype and emp id.
I'm using below code but it's not showing total leave balance.

```
private void cbleavetype_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=........")
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select leave from leaveallotment where id='" + comboBox1.Text + "' && leavetype='" + cbleavetype.Text + "'",conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(tbl);
    // Show total leave in textBox1
    textBox1.Text = cbleavetype.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: **Use parameters to your queries!**

Comment: Aside from @Yuck's comment, right now you are showing the selected leave type in `testBox`. You need to actually do the math with the data you got from the database query.

Comment: used this but not showing leave balance  
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select leave from leaveallotment where id=@id and leavetype=@leavetype");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",comboBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@leavetype",cbleavetype.Text);

Answer (score 0):

I think one thing that needs to happen is to change '&&' to 'and'

Comment: try  textBox1.Text = tbl.rows[0]["leave"].ToString();

Answer (score -1):

You can use this below code snipset,

```
        connectionString.Open();
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(
                "select LeaveCount from leaveallotment  where
                 id= '" + comboBox1.Text + "' and 
                 leavetype='" + comboBox2.Text + "'",
                connectionString);
        SqlDataReader da = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (da.Read()) {
            textBox1.Text = da["LeaveCount"].ToString();
        }
        connectionString.Close();
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection and should not be used.

Comment: Can you explain why this is vulnerable to SQL injection?